# android changing language date

Tags: android, date

I have a working app in english.

But when i change the language of the device to french i get an exception.

In an activity i do the following:

```
send(new Date.tostring());
```

and send it to another activity where i want to get the date back.

```
public method (String stringDate){
new Date(date.parse(stringDate));
}
```

This works fine as long as I'm in English mode.
But when i go to the settings and change the language to French (so my app will be in french)
I get an illegalargumentException, and he can't parse the string to a date.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of sending string to construct date, you should use `getTime()` method to send milliseconds as long value. its the proper way to pass date and reconstruct it. for e.g.

to send:

```
long value = new Date().getTime();
```

to reconstruct:

```
Date d = new Date(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it related to the (possibly) different date systems used in different languages/locales?

for instance:

```
Imagine the following date: 02/04/03
Which does it mean?
  2nd of April 2003    (European style)
  4th of February 2003 (USA style)
  3rd of April 2002
```

(taken from: http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/iso-date)

Note: I've never developed for Android. This is just a guess